# Listing SSRS subscriptions with user-defined descriptions

Tags: web-services, reporting-services

We have a growing number of non-data-driven SSRS 2008 subscriptions and the default list in SSRS does not provide any way to indicate what each subscription is all about.  Yes, there is a description but it is auto-generated and not very helpful.  We need it to say "Company ABC Quarterly to Managers", for instance.

I looked at using the ReportingService2010 web service and managed to not only read each report's description but modify it.  However, as soon as someone edits the subscription from SSRS, which will be required sometimes, the description reverts to the auto-generated one.

Although I have never worked with data-driven reports, I wonder whether these will provide the functionality that I need.  It just seems like a lot of work to set up, given that I don't really need the subscriptions to be data-driven.

Am I missing something simple here?  Is this simple functionality something that comes with upgrading to a newer SSRS version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing something simple here? Is this simple functionality
>   something that comes with upgrading to a newer SSRS version?

It [does not appear that standard subscriptions in SSRS 2012 allow descriptions to be entered either](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156307) (I couldn't find a screenshot of the UI though).

> Although I have never worked with data-driven reports, I wonder
>   whether these will provide the functionality that I need. It just
>   seems like a lot of work to set up, given that I don't really need the
>   subscriptions to be data-driven.

I would argue against the need for data-driven subscriptions if standard subscriptions are fulfilling the business need. Would this be worth your time and effort? If it is, the obvious advantage is that subscription descriptions are editable in the UI, and do not appear to be overwritten when modifying the subscription.

**If you're still interested in using standard subscriptions...**

One way to "hack" SSRS such that the subscriptions will not overwrite the description (which isn't editable in the UI anyway) would be to modify the stored procedure ReportServer.dbo.UpdateSubscription.

*DISCLAIMER: Use the following advice at your own risk. **This involves modifying a standard sproc that Reporting Services relies on.***

You can alter the update statement such that the description value would only be modified if the subscription is not a data-driven subscription (we do not want to break data-driven subscription descriptions, which *are* editable in the UI). In the stored procedure, you can distinguish data-driven subscriptions from standard subscriptions by looking at the value of @DataSettings. If it `IS NULL`, then it is a plain old subscription. If it `IS NOT NULL`, then we're looking at a data-driven subscription.

The following line in the Update statement:

```
[Description] = @Description,
```

Can be changed to:

```
[Description] = CASE WHEN @DataSettings IS NULL THEN [Description]
                        ELSE @Description
                    END,
```

This would keep all standard subscription descriptions the same when they are modified in SSRS, but allow data-driven subscription descriptions to be modified.

Comment: I don't think the DB team would allow this solution, though I do appreciate it.  For now, my solution is to use the email subject value instead of the subscription description value.  (All of our subscriptions involve emailing the results.)  

Moderators: Should I answer my own question with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Per Mat's Mug, I am noting the solution that I eventually used:

Since all of our subscriptions involve emailing the report, we could get away with re-purposing the email subject field as the description.  This way it was possible to produce a listing of all subscriptions and show an arbitrary description for each one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an expansion on the hack from dev_etter.  I was able to use the Stored Procedure @parameter input along with a new Report Parameter (pReportParameterName) to create a dynamic, user controllable description that's unique to the report.

- Add a new hidden text parameter to the report (pReportParameterName)
- Add the Code Block 1 below in Stored Procedure UpdateSubscription above the UPDATE statement.
- Change the 'Description = ' line of the UPDATE statement to something like Code Block 2 below.

With that set up, create or edit a Timed Subscription and enter the desired text into the Description parameter.  After saving you should see the entered description in the Description column of the Subscriptions screen.

```
/*** Code Block 1 ***/
DECLARE @Param as XML = CAST(@Parameters as XML)
DECLARE @MY_Description as varchar(512)

SELECT  @MY_Description = e.f.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar (100)')
FROM (select 1 id, @Param xCol) tx
    CROSS APPLY tx.xCol.nodes('./ParameterValues/ParameterValue') AS a(b)
    CROSS APPLY a.b.nodes('./Name') AS c(d)
    CROSS APPLY a.b.nodes('./Value') AS e(f)
WHERE c.d.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar (100)') LIKE 'pReportParameterName'

   /*** Code Block 2 ***/
    [Description] = --@Description
                    CASE 
                        WHEN @DataSettings IS NULL 
                             AND @MY_Description IS NOT NULL 
                             THEN @MY_Description
                        ELSE @Description
                    END,
```

Cheers,
Sj